# Max and concavity

Tags: convex-optimization

Let $x,y$ be two probability vectors belonging to the simplex of size $n$ (denote by $\Delta_n$) and $f(x,y) = x^{\top}Ay - \epsilon||x||_2^2-\epsilon ||y||_2^2$ with $\epsilon>0.$ Is it true that $$g(x) = \max_{y \in \Delta_n} f(x,y)$$ is a concave function?

Comment: Please note that Danskin's theorem is not applicable here.

Comment: You are asking in the wrong forum.

Comment: Without some assumptions about $A$, obviously, not. Let $\varepsilon=0$ and let $A=Id$. Then for vectors $x$ consisting of $n-1$ zeroes and one $1$, the maximum is $1$ (with $y=x$) while for $x=(1/n,\dots,1.n)$ it is $1/n$ (for any $y$). Subtracting $\varepsilon$ terms with sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$ won't change anything. So, what are the restrictions on $A$?